# jQuery - Limit groups of labels and checkboxes to a max number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to limit a max number selectable for `checkboxes` and their relative `labels`. Checkboxes work fine but labels are still selectable more than the limit.

My html `input` is formed like this:

```
<div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group bizmoduleselect">
<label id="b-<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" class="btn btn-default <?php echo $labelchk ?>">
    <div class="bizcontent">
        <input id="youaresure" type="checkbox" name="email_cats[]" <?php echo $chk ?> value="<?php echo $term->term_id ?>" />
        <h5><?php echo $term->name ?></h5>
    </div>
</label>
</div>
```

and my jQuery to limit checkboxes and labels is like:

```
var $checkboxes = $('input[id="youaresure"]');
var $parent = $checkboxes.parent('label');
var max = 5;
$checkboxes.show();
$checkboxes.change(function () {
    $(this).prop('checked', function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            return ($checkboxes.filter(':checked').length <= max) ? true : false;
        }
    });
});
$parent.show();
$parent.change(function () {
    $(this).prop('class', function () {
        if ($(this).is('active')) {
            return ($parent.filter('active').length <= max) ? true : false;
        }
    }
```

Basically, php inserts an `active` class to `labels` parents of `inputs:checked` and I should prevent both `labels` and `inputs` to be selected **if more than 5**.
For checkboxes is fine but parent labels are still selectable and basically are the visible ones.

**EDIT**: I've forgotten to indicate that it works with bootstrap and each checkbox is threaten like a button!

Comment: plz add your complete code to jsfiddle

Comment: Labels don't have change event. So you can either use label click event or do all on the checkbox change event.

Comment: can't duplicate Id's in a page, they are unique by definition

Comment: Thanks guys. I've exactly used [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-select-tiled-layout) snippet with bootstrap 3. It's probably for this reason I can't block to click checkboxes once the limit is reached. They're treated like buttons. [link](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-select-tiled-layout) @MohammadAkbari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `change` event on `<label>`. Everything should be done in event handler of the `<input>`

My suggestion is you disable the other checkboxes when limit is reached.

Following will toggle the active class on label as well as disable/enable unchecked inputs

```
var max = 5;

var $checkboxes = $(':checkbox').change(function(e) {
  var maxChecked = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length === max;
  // disable/enable others based on limit 
  $checkboxes.not(':checked').prop('disabled', maxChecked);
  // toggle label active based on checked state
  $(this).closest('label').toggleClass('active', this.checked);
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/r9dotfng/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but I've tried your solution and it won't work. I've checked my code and I've actually forgotten that it works with bootstrap data-toggle="buttons". I've edited the question. Probably it's for that! I've actually used [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-select-tiled-layout) snippet.

Comment: I mean checkboxes are treated like buttons!

Comment: Thanks I've finally arrived to the solution starting from your answer. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn’t work because of label has no change handler. Maybe you should better to add your some code into your checkbox’s property check function that removes ‘active’ class of parent labels if necessary.